# PHP PDFTK and Media Temple

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, mediatemple, pdftk

1. Has anyone ever been able to install PDFTK on Media Temple GS?
   1.a. If so, how?
2. If not, is there anyway to merge PDF and FDF so the user get's served the PDF version with the FDF data?

The reason is, if the user downloads the FDF data, they need access to the PDF as well which sits on the server, and if they are Offline, I want them to just have the full PDF vs. just the FDF.

Any thoughts or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I too would like to know if you got this working.

Comment: I actually left MediaTemple, to a new server.... so in short, I never got it working.